# Windows service start issue with ServiceController class for few machines

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm having a window service and tried to start it by using ServiceController class from an windows application and it's working fine for few systems, but this is failing in few systems and giving exception like below.

[image: Error that I'm getting]

Below is the sample code that I've written to start the service, also I don't want to do any manual changes to the target machine in order to start the service.

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("SampleService");

if (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running) || service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending))
{
   Bservice.Stop();
}
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
service.Start(arguments);
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
```

Am I missing anything from the code snippet? or please help me out how can i get rid of this.

Even I've commented out all the code in the service like it's empty service now, but with code and without code I'm getting same below error any idea??

```
    Application: ECApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.Reflection.AssemblyName)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveAssembly(BamlAssembly)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlTypeToType(BamlType)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(BamlType, Int16)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetXamlType(Int16)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_ConstructorParameterType()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_OneBamlRecord()
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.ReadKeys()
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.SetDeferrableContent(System.Windows.DeferrableContent)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext+<>c.<Create_BamlProperty_ResourceDictionary_DeferrableContent>b__297_0(System.Object, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(System.Object, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(System.Xaml.XamlMember, System.Object, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlMember, System.Object)

Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri)
   at ECApp.Presentation.App.InitializeComponent()
   at ECApp.Presentation.App.Main()
```

The above exception is coming only when I install service using commad 'sc create "service name" ...' but when I install service using 'Installutil.exe "service"' then I'm getting no issues don't know why? Any reasons??

Comment: In some machines it work and in some no?

Comment: Check if after calling the stop the process still exists. I had the same problem yesterday ... The service was stopped but the process still existed preventing it from opening. On my case was one thread that was not aborted correctly.

Comment: and check the windows EventViewer, maybe you can get more details

Comment: The application isn't installed on the machine or an object is missing on the machine.  Try starting the application using the executable and see what is happening.  Did you check to see if the service was already started?  You can check to see if the IP is listing from cmd.exe > netstat -a which will give a list of TCP and UDP connections to see if an application is already using the port number.

Comment: @ilansch Yes few machines I'm getting the above error and service starts perfectly for other machines. :(

Comment: Which service account is run this service ? Is the default service account or it is executed under some user account ?  Also can you check the "System" logs from Local eventviewer where this service is not starting.  Under source "Service Control manager" you may find some error logs.

Comment: So its not coding. Its enviromnet issue. A "system" problem

Comment: Perhaps it is taking longer than 30 seconds for your service to start on some machines?

Comment: Hi All, I've updated my post with error that I'm getting at event viewer and getting the same error with empty service i.e. commented out all the code and with all the code.

Comment: Also the above exception is coming only when I install service using commad 'sc create "service" ...' but when I install service using 'Installutil.exe "service" ' then I'm getting no issues don't know why? Any reasons??